# Time varying matrix having constant eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove that the eigenvalues of a time varying matrix $A(t)=e^{A_{1}t}A(0)e^{-A_{1}t}$ are independent of $t$. Can anyone please throw in a clue for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A(0)$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. What happens to $e^{A_1 t} v$ when you apply $A(t)$ to it?

Comment: Thank you. I've worked out the proof from your clue: if $\lambda$ and $v$ are eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A(0)$ then by using definition $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A(t)$ with $e^{A_{1}t}v$ being the corresponding eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-A_{1}t}= \left[e^{A_{1}t}\right]^{-1}$$

so $A(t)$ is related to $A(0)$ by a similarity transformation ( which preserves eigenvalues)

if a square matrix $B$ has eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$

Then the matrix $C=XBX^{-1}$ has eigenvector $Xv$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$

$$C(Xv) = XBX^{-1}Xv=XBv=\lambda (Xv) $$